# Writing program for guessing a number in Small basic but the program won't run

Tags: random, smallbasic

this is the code I'm using

```
Sub btnguess_Click
  
  randNum = Math.GetRandomNumber(10)
  FCControls.GetText(txtCels)
  
  If txtCels = randNum Then
    lblanswer = "That's correct the Madame would like to hire you!"
  ElseIf txtCels <1 or >10 Then
    lblanswer = "Please enter number between 1 and 10"
  Elseif txtCels <> randNum Then
    lblanswer = "That's incorrect the Madame asks you to leave."
    EndIf
  
endsub
```

error that I'm getting : 45,24:Expected a condition here.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at `ElseIf txtCels <1 or >10 Then`

When specifying a statement, you can't leave out a condition even if previously mentioned.

You'll have to re-write `txtCels` before the `>10`, i.e.

```
ElseIf txtCels <1 or txtCels >10 Then
```

Without this, you're essentially saying 'greater than 10' by itself, which makes no sense.

Comment: I just tried it that and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I'm assuming it's got to do with "FCControls.GetText(txtCels)", is FCControls a library you imported earlier?

Comment: yea the teacher for the class wants us to do it this way

Comment: could you paste the code here? just to see the libraries used

Comment: what do you mean and how would i do that

Comment: could you paste all of your code here as a comment?